# Remote Deployment with Mule CE

Tags: maven, deployment, mule

What is the recommended/available approaches to remote deploying a Mule application to a remote Mule server? I'm using Maven for build btw.

I saw that the appkit can remote deploy to Cloudhub: http://blogs.mulesoft.org/using-continuous-deployment-with-cloudhub/

and theres a rest maven plugin for the management console but I'm using the standalone community edition and can not use either one. I also saw a cargo implementation on Github, but this only handle local deployments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would write a script that:

- scp the application to /tmp
- remote mv the application to $MULE/apps

Moving a file being an atomic operation prevents potential issues of uploading directly in the /apps directory and have Mule pick-up a partially uploaded application.

Comment: Would you suggest keeping that away from Maven? And just executing it from a CI server?

Comment: You will still need Maven to build/release your app. You can have your CI server use Maven to build snapshots and push them to a staging environment automatically. So Maven stays :)

Answer (score 0):

"scp the application to /tmp" reminds me [this](http://evgeny-goldin.com/wiki/Copy-maven-plugin)! ...